# Internet explorer missing from assigned access list

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-8.1, kiosk

I'm attempting to use windows 8.1 assigned access mode to create a kiosk displaying an interactive website.  The problem I'm coming up against is that there are no browsers is the list of available apps.  I know it is possible to use Internet Explorer as the selected app, but I cannot find anything that tells me how to add it to the list.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you try running desktop IE in kiosk mode instead? `iexplore -k [URL]`

Answer (score 1):

You have to login as the kiosk-user at least once to activate the user and install all apps. for IE to work you also have to start the metro version of IE to initialize it. there you can change the settings so IE works as you want it when used in kiosk mode.
Then change back to administrator and you should be able to choose IE from the list.

I hope I could help :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  I was building several Win8.1 tablets to use as kiosks.  Everything worked fine except for one instance when IE wouldn't show up on the apps list for assigned access.  So I eventually just deleted the local user I had created and then immediately recreated it.  After signing on and letting it install all the 8.1 apps, I logged back into my admin, set the newly created account for assigned access, and IE showed up again as available for assigned access use.